# getting 500 error in wordpress on file upload. its showing HTTP error

Tags: wordpress

getting 500 error in wordpress on file upload. its showing HTTP error. screenshot is attached

[image: Error]

Comment: Are you using linux/ubuntu ?

Comment: But what server are you using in live ???

If you are using linux in live than, possibility of permissions issues in your upload directory.

Comment: or you exceeded size limit.

Comment: linux server. i have given all(r-w etc) permission to wp-content folder

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your functions.php

```
    add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'change_graphic_lib' );

    function change_graphic_lib($array) {
    return array( 'WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick' );
    }
```